# Error: Cannot find module when using decorators

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I am trying to use decorators in my typescript class.
This is what I am trying

```ts
import {
  Model,
  ModelCtor
} from 'sequelize/types';

function decorator(constructor) {
  // 
}

@decorator
class Service implements IService {
  // when using 'private User:  any' instead it works fine 
  constructor(private User: ModelCtor < Model < any, any >> ) {
      
  }
}
```

I get the following error: `Error: Cannot find module 'sequelize/types'`
In this particular example I am importing `sequelize/types` but it works the same for any other `d.ts` file.

I have installed the types and work fine without decorators. Also It does not complain when defining type to `any` for the constructor param: `private User: any`

I searched but didn't found something useful.

By the way, my tsconfig.json is:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
 "target": "es5",
 "module": "commonjs",
 "outDir": "./build",
 "sourceMap": true,
 "typeRoots": [
   "./node_modules/@types",
   "./lib/types/index",
   "./node_modules/sequelize/types/"
 ],
 "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
 "experimentalDecorators": true,
 "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
 "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
 "moduleResolution": "node",
 "pretty": true,
 "allowJs": true,
 "noEmit": false,
 "esModuleInterop": true,
},
"include": [
 "./index.ts",
 "./lib"
],
"exclude": [
 "node_modules",
 "tests",
 ".vscode",
 "doc",

]
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I was compiling TypeScript with `--transpile-only` flag.

This was resolved for my specific case by removing this flag